# Determine the conditional probability $P\big( X>\frac{3}{4} \big| Y = \frac{1}{2}\big)$.

Tags: conditional-probability, density-function

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables with joint density function

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\begin{cases} 8xy \space \text{ for } 0<y<x<1\\ 0 \space\space\space\space\space\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

Determine the conditional probability $P\big( X>\frac{3}{4} \big| Y = \frac{1}{2}\big)$.

Is the answer $\frac{5}{12}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guide:

Having a look at the density with fixed $y=\frac12$ we find the function:$$g_{X}\left(x\right)=f_{X,Y}\left(x,\frac{1}{2}\right)=\begin{cases}
4x & \text{for }\frac{1}{2}<x<1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

This function $g_{X}$ has in a certain sense the *shape* of the PDF
of $X$ under condition $Y=\frac{1}{2}$.

However we cannot promote it to *be* this PDF because it is not a PDF.

Missing is that we do not have $\int g_{X}\left(x\right)dx=1$ as
is necessary for a PDF.

This however can repaired taking $cg_{X}\left(x\right)$ as PDF where
$c$ denotes a constant such that $\int cg_{X}\left(x\right)dx=1$.

Based on the equality $\int cg_{X}\left(x\right)dx=1$ we can easily
find this $c$.

Comment: Did you get 5/12 as the final answer?

Comment: No. $P\left(X>a\mid Y=\frac{1}{2}\right)=\int_{a}^{1}\frac{8}{3}xdx=\left[\frac{4}{3}x^{2}\right]_{a}^{1}=\frac{4}{3}\left(1-a^{2}\right)$
so $P\left(X>\frac{3}{4}\mid Y=\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{4}{3}\left(1-\frac{9}{16}\right)=\frac{7}{12}$.

Comment: Why is the top limit 1?

Comment: $X$ takes values in interval $[y,1]$ according to the definition in your question. So under condition $y=\frac12$ it will take values in $[\frac12,1]$. The density is $0$ for values that exceed $1$.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y=y\}=\int_A f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)\,\mathrm d x,$$
where $$f_{X\mid Y=y}(x)=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\int_{\mathbb R}f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,\mathrm d x}=\frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)}.$$

Comment: so I got 4x for the numerator and 3/2 for the denominator